# Tensorflow object detection evaluation

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, evaluation

I like to evaluate  my object detection model with mAP (mean average precision). In https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/utils/ there is object_detection_evaluation.py that I want to use.

I use following for the groundtruth boxes:

```
pascal_evaluator = object_detection_evaluation.PascalDetectionEvaluator(
    categories, matching_iou_threshold=0.1)

groundtruth_boxes = np.array([[10, 10, 11, 11]], dtype=float)
groundtruth_class_labels = np.array([1], dtype=int)

groundtruth_is_difficult_list = np.array([False], dtype=bool)

pascal_evaluator.add_single_ground_truth_image_info(
    'img2',
    {
        standard_fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_boxes: groundtruth_boxes,
        standard_fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_classes: groundtruth_class_labels,
        standard_fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_difficult: groundtruth_is_difficult_list
    }
)
```

and this for the prediction Boxes:

```
# Add detections
image_key = 'img2'
detected_boxes = np.array(
    [ [100, 100, 220, 220], [10, 10, 11, 11]],
    dtype=float)
detected_class_labels = np.array([1,1], dtype=int)
detected_scores = np.array([0.8, 0.9], dtype=float)
pascal_evaluator.add_single_detected_image_info(image_key, {
    standard_fields.DetectionResultFields.detection_boxes:
        detected_boxes,
    standard_fields.DetectionResultFields.detection_scores:
        detected_scores,
    standard_fields.DetectionResultFields.detection_classes:
        detected_class_labels
})
```

I print the results with

```
metrics = pascal_evaluator.evaluate()
print(metrics)
```

And my Question:

if I use this prediction Boxes `[100, 100, 220, 220]`, `[10, 10, 11, 11]` the result is:

> {'PASCAL/Precision/mAP@0.1IOU': 1.0,
>   'PASCAL/PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.1IOU/face': 1.0}

If I use `[10, 10, 11, 11]`, `[100, 100, 220, 220]` (other Box sequence)

I get following result:

> {'PASCAL/Precision/mAP@0.1IOU': 0.5,
>   'PASCAL/PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.1IOU/face': 0.5}

Why is that so? Or is it bug?

Cheers Michael

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not so clear about it I think I found the error in your code. You mentioned you get different results for different order of bounding boxes. This seems peculiar and if true then it was surely a bug.

But, since I tested the code myself, you probably *did not change the corresponding scores* (`detected_scores = np.array([0.8, 0.9], dtype=float)`) to the bounding boxes. But this way you changes also the problem not just the order of the bounding boxes. If you apply the correct bounding boxes the mAP remains the same in both cases:

> {'PascalBoxes_Precision/mAP@0.5IOU': 1.0,
>   'PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/person': 1.0}